# How do I memorize mathematical proofs?

Tags: proof-writing, self-learning, learning

I first started wanting to know about the derivation of theorems because certain ones help you memorize the theorems better.

But as I take harder math classes, it turns out better for me to use other mnemonic tricks. But I still want to know about proof and derivation because I guess I am curious and feel uncomfortable with something that comes out of nowhere.

But as some people ask for to prove things for them, I start to notice I often forgot the proofs.

It usually happen like this: I can write down the first few steps of the proof. (At least I can start it) But I often got stuck and don't know where to continue from.

Take for example, this simple proof of logarithm change of base formula, I saw on wiki proof: let $$y=\log_b x \iff b^y=x$$
$$z=\log_a x \iff a^z=x$$
Then, $$z=\log_a (b^y)$$
$$=y\log_a b$$
$$=\log_b x \log_a b$$

I read this like 1 week ago. Today , I try reciting this proof. I got the first 2 line down on paper. (The "let" conditions) Then I got stuck and had to go back on to the site again.

Comment: Regarding the title: don't.

Comment: @dREaM why. Care to leave an answer?

Comment: Why are you memorizing proofs line for line? The point of reading proofs is to understand the "big ideas", the overarching picture of why the result is true. Then even if you forget the tiny details of a proof you should still be able to reconstruct the basic argument